# Hibernate duplicates record along with null value(new row as duplicate) while saving

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-criteria

I am getting following issue while saving entity in hibernate -

It duplicates the record with null values -

(2661956,2601555,**'Chloe','Chloe','Thooks'**,null,null,null,null,null,null,'Y','N','XYZ',to_date('15-NOV-16','DD-MON-RR'),null,null)

with a duplicate -

(2661946,2601555,**null,null,null**,null,null,null,null,null,null,'Y','N','XYZ',to_date('15-NOV-16','DD-MON-RR'),null,null) -

We have the following mapping -

Parent -

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping default-lazy="false">
    <class name="com.sm.persistence.LOADetailBO" table="LOADETAILS">

        <id name="loaDetailsId" type="long">
            <column name="LOA_ID" precision="38" scale="0"/>
            <generator class="com.sm.persistence.dao.seqgen.LOADetailSeqGen">
            </generator>
        </id>
        <many-to-one name="reregistration" class="com.sm.persistence.RerBO" fetch="join">
            <column name="RER_ID" precision="38" scale="0"/>
        </many-to-one>
        <property name="relatedPlanManager" type="string">
            <column name="RELATED_PLAN_MANAGER"/>
        </property>
        <property name="relatedPlanManagerCode" type="string">
            <column name="RELATED_PLAN_MANAGER_CODE"/>
        </property>
        <set name="relatedPlanManagerAddress" inverse="true" cascade="all-delete-orphan">
            <key>
                <column name="LOA_ID" precision="38" scale="0" not-null="false"/>
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="com.sm.persistence.AddressBO" />
        </set>
        <set name="corporateCustomers" inverse="true" cascade="all-delete-orphan">
            <key>
                <column name="LOA_ID" precision="38" scale="0" not-null="false"/>
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="com.sm.persistence.CorporateCustomerBO" />
        </set>
        <set name="privateCustomers" inverse="true" cascade="all-delete-orphan">
            <key>
                <column name="LOA_ID" precision="38" scale="0" not-null="false" />
            </key>            
            <one-to-many class="com.sm.persistence.PrivateCustomerBO"/>
        </set>
        <set name="unwrappedAccount"  inverse="true" cascade="all-delete-orphan">
            <key>
                <column name="LOA_ID" precision="38" scale="0" not-null="false"/>
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="com.sm.persistence.UnwrappedAccountBO" />
        </set>
        <set name="wrappedAccount" inverse="true" cascade="all-delete-orphan">
            <key>
                <column name="LOA_ID" precision="38" scale="0" not-null="false" />
            </key>            
            <one-to-many class="com.sm.persistence.WrappedAccountBO"/>
        </set>       
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Child -

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping default-lazy="false">
    <class name="com.sm.persistence.PrivateCustomerBO" table="RER_CUSTOMER_DETAIL">

        <id name="privateCustomerId" type="long">
            <column name="RERE_CUSTOMER_ID" precision="38" scale="0"/>
            <generator class="com.sm.persistence.dao.seqgen.PrivateCustomerSeqGen">
            </generator>
        </id>
        <many-to-one name="loaDetail" class="com.sm.persistence.LOADetailBO" fetch="join">
            <column name="LOA_DETAILS_ID" precision="38" scale="0"/>
        </many-to-one>
        <property name="title" type="string">
            <column name="TITLE"/>
        </property>
        <property name="firstName" type="string">
            <column name="FIRST_NAME"/>
        </property>
        <property name="surname" type="string">
            <column name="SURNAME"/>
        </property>
        <set name="address" inverse="false" cascade="all-delete-orphan">
            <key>
                <column name="PRIVATE_CUSTOMER_ID" precision="38" scale="0" not-null="false"/>
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="com.sm.persistence.AddressBO" />
        </set>
        <property name="primary" type="string">
            <column name="IS_PRIMARY"/>
        </property>
        <property name="corporate" type="string">
            <column name="IS_CORPORATE"/>
        </property>
        <!--<property name="dateofBirth" type="string">
            <column name="DATE_OF_BIRTH"/>
        </property>-->     
        <property name="nationalInsurance" type="string">
            <column name="NINO"/>
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I checked parent object both pre and post save and can't find any object with null value populated. However, when I fetch the object hierarchy with criteria api it returns duplicate record with null.

Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer:

1. PrivateCustomerBO is a child of LOADetailBO. So when your java code
   saves a PrivateCustomerBO object it will write to all tables
   specified against these 2 objects: RER_CUSTOMER_DETAIL = primary
   table for PrivateCustomerBO, LOADETAILS = primary table for
   LOADetailBO, ***plus all tables referenced by these two objects via
   many-to-one or one-to-many mappings***.  CORRECT BEHAVIOUR
2. Expanding the bolded bit above, LOADetailBO is referenced by
   PrivateCustomerBO via:
   `<many-to-one name="loaDetail" class="com.sm.persistence.LOADetailBO" fetch="join">
           <column name="LOA_DETAILS_ID" precision="38" scale="0"/>
       </many-to-one>`
   This means that LOADETAILS is additionally referenced as a related
   table, not just a parent and a second row is written (in this case
   there is some data missing (NULL) because your program hasn't
   populated it for the referenced entity).  INCORRECT BEHAVIOUR.

Fix: remove the many-to-one mapping shown above (it's redundant and covered by parent).

Comment: I tried but its still inserting null record. I checked Set Object also it doesn't have any null populated object.

Comment: The table populated twice is LOADDETAILS, right?

If so, then I have a strong feeling the above explanation must be right.  Double check you've deleted all data, removed the many-to-one name="loaDetail and do a full project clean & make sure you regenerate hibernate objs during build.  :)